# Merging multiple rows together in a ListView if they match a certain criteria?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` that keeps track of amount paid, if user makes a payment twice using the same type of payment then those two entries on the List should be merged together as one and amount added.

```
Payment 1 - $50  - Check
Payment 2 - $100 - Check
```

The above looks like so in the ListView:

```
$150 - Check
$50 - Check
```

So the amounts are indeed being added but my logic to remove the row holding the $50 amount does not work... Not quite sure why but the point is to merge them together and remove that unnecessary row holding the $50.

Here is the relevant code from my update method and the `getView` method from a Adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter<ClassObject>`.

**getView()**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payscreen_tab2_listgrid_row, null);
    }

    //Get item from list 
    InvoiceListModel item = this.getItem(position);
    if (item != null) {
        TextView txtAmount        = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.PayScreen_Tab2_Columns_txtAmount);
        TextView txtPaidBy        = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.PayScreen_Tab2_Columns_txtPaidBy);

        txtPaidBy.setText(item.paidBy);
        txtAmount.setText(item.amount);
    }

    return v;
}
```

**Adapter custom update method**

```
 public boolean update(InvoiceListModel object){
        for(int x=0; x< uiListViewCollectionData.size(); x++){
            InvoiceListModel tempObj = uiListViewCollectionData.get(x);
            if(tempObj != null &&
               tempObj.paidBy.equals(object.paidBy)){

                //Set the data on the temp object
                tempObj.amount  = uiListViewCollectionData.get(x).amount.plus(object.amount);

                //Remove the old outdated object from datasource
                uiListViewCollectionData.remove(x);
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //Add the new model containing the new amount back to list
                uiListViewCollectionData.add(tempObj);
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure `notifyDataSetChanged()` is `async` and this is causing the next line to quickly execute. Is it possible to directly render the `ListView` UI component right then and there as soon as I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you pass the data to the list?

You should 'repack' your old_data and pass new_data to the adapter. Something like:

```
new_data = repack (old_data);
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(new_data);
```

So, if old_data have 50 items, new data will have only 35 (as example), and you present this 35 items in the list. Merging logic should be out of the getView().

Comment: I see what you mean, I will test this out.